# Hover Property on splash screen header causes header to translate up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QuiZA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <h1 class="frontlogo">QuiZA Logo </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ducimus libero culpa ipsum cupiditate quasi accusantium quibusdam soluta, dolorem iure sapiente ut consectetur cum minus id repellat amet perspiciatis fuga?</p>
        <!--Loading screen will start after this-->
      <div class="splash">
        <h1 class="splash-header">Press Here...</h1>
    </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```
.container{
    background: darkgoldenrod;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
}
.splash{
    cursor: none;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-300px);
    transition: all ease-in-out 600ms;
}
.hidden{
    transition: 2.0s;
    display: none;
}
.splash-header{
    height: 90%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    transform: translateY(30%);
}
.splash-header:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
.frontlogo{
    height: 90%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

I am currently developing a quiz application for studying my undergrad work using HTML; CSS; and JS. I am trying to code a starting splash screen that will fade away when pressed. I am having trouble with the hover property I am trying to implement on the splash screen header. The statement `transform: scale(1.5);` makes the text jump to the top of the splash container. I want it to stay in the same place but just get bigger, as well as I would want the hover to be an animation that is smooth instead of just static if that makes sense.

I've tried to change the positioning of the header using align-items, fixed positioning (top, left), and transform: translateY in the Hover class of the splash header. None of this has given the result I wish for.

[JSFiddle Link first attempt with fiddle never used before.](https://jsfiddle.net/configgle/hL0axt8r/1/#&togetherjs=vAK48tKyP4)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: As @Paulie_D stated in his comment, providing all the relevant HTML, CSS and JavaScript needed to reproduce the issue would rock! Once you've added this (HTML & JavaScript) people will be able to assist you.

Comment: I understand I should have better clarified that I have yet to implement any javascript but I do have my HTML code how would I go about adding the HTML code to the above CSS code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The two main issues I saw you were running into are:

1. Your flexbox styling was inside of your H1 styling rather than inside of your H1 container. Flexbox styling effects the container and how the container should interact with the items inside of it, rather than each item individually (from a broad strokes perspective)
2. You are using transform styling which is throwing off your transitions when triggered. I instead used margins to get the splash in the right location and this solved your header issue.

```css
.container{
    background: darkgoldenrod;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
}
.splash{
    cursor: none;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hidden{
    transition: 2.0s;
    display: none;
}
.splash-header{
    color: white;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
.splash-header:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
.frontlogo{
    height: 90%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QuiZA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <h1 class="frontlogo">QuiZA Logo </h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit ducimus libero culpa ipsum cupiditate quasi accusantium quibusdam soluta, dolorem iure sapiente ut consectetur cum minus id repellat amet perspiciatis fuga?</p>
        <!--Loading screen will start after this-->
      <div class="splash">
        <h1 class="splash-header">Press Here...</h1>
    </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that, my knowledge on flex/grid display is still patchy. I better understand that the splash needed to be flex in order to better manipulate the heading. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The flexbox styling needed to be applied to the splash. Let me know if there's anything else you need help with